# Are there other countries aside the U.S. that advanced protection beyond the standards mandated by TRIPS?

Tags: united-states, international, trade, wto

> TRIPS-plus conditions mandating standards beyond TRIPS have also been
> the subject of scrutiny.[37] These FTA agreements contain conditions
> that limit the ability of governments to introduce competition for
> generic producers. In particular, the United States has been
> criticised for advancing protection well beyond the standards mandated
> by TRIPS. The United States Free Trade Agreements with Australia,
> Morocco and Bahrain have extended patentability by requiring patents
> be available for new uses of known products.[38] The TRIPS agreement
> allows the grant of compulsory licenses at a nation's discretion.
> TRIPS-plus conditions in the United States' FTAs with Australia,
> Jordan, Singapore and Vietnam have restricted the application of
> compulsory licenses to emergency situations, antitrust remedies, and
> cases of public non-commercial use.[38]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIPS_Agreement

Are there other countries aside the U.S. that advanced protection beyond the standards mandated by TRIPS? The article mentions that the U.S. advanced protection well beyond the standards mandated by TRIPS, but it doesn't mention other countries. The article says well beyond, but I am wondering if other countries might have done the same but to a lesser, equal or greater degree.

Comment: It is hard to parse what is being asked in term of specific examples.